# Room update how to update only new filed is not null ,skip null new field

Tags: android-room

there is a table :

```
@Entity(tableName = "users")
data class UserEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false) var id: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "username") var name: String?,
    var onlineShowOpen: Boolean?,
    var summary:String?
)
```

,first I insert a data ,like this `UserEntity(id:"12",name:"123",onlineShowOpen:false,summary:"123")` ,
then I want to use `UserEntity(id:"12",name:"123",onlineShowOpen:true,summary:null)` to update by

```
   @Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun updateUser(User: UserEntity): Int
```

,then I find the result is `UserEntity(id:"12",name:"123",onlineShowOpen:true,summary:null)` ,
but I expect the result is `UserEntity(id:"12",name:"123",onlineShowOpen:true,summary:"123")`。
I do not know how to skip the null data when update,
please help me !

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
@Query("UPDATE users SET onlineShowOpen = 0 WHERE id=:id")
fun otherUpdateUser(id: String): Int
```

either that or make sure that all other values, if use the convenience (i.e. limited) as as they should be. That is the convenience `@Update` uses what is effectively `UPDATE users SET name=:name, onlineShowOpen=:onlineShowOpen, summary=:summary WHERE id=:id` *(where the values preceded by a `:` are obtained from the object passed to it)*.

Comment: Thank you . But what should I do in this scenario?After Json obtained from the API are converted into objects like User, there are very very many  fields ,about 20 . and some fields are null ,but i can't know which fields are null 。

Comment: @qianqian the answer will ignore other columns they will remain as they were i.e. unchanged. If you wish to consider those values as whether or not the onlineShowOpen is changed then the WHERE clause would have to reflect this. e.g. `.... WHERE id=:id AND summary IS NOT NULL`.